# Function as Parameter with either two or three paramteres

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Constructor which takes a function as parameter:

```dart
Entity({
 Widget Function(BuildContext context, String text) builder,
});
```

And I'm calling it like that:

```dart
new Entity(
  builder: (context, text) => Text(text),
)
```

Now I wan to add a third optional parameter to the function like:

```dart
Widget Function(BuildContext context, String text, int index)
```

Is there a way to do this without the need to change all my constructor calls? 
So that both `builder: (c, text) => ...` and `builder: (c, text, int) => ...` can be used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Dart 2.7, this is not feasible in a type-safe way, as it would require "union types", which Dart doesn't have.

Your best bet would be to have two different parameters:

```dart
Entity(builder: (BuildContext context, String text) => ...);

Entity(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, String text, int index) => ...);
```